# Vue js doesn't update data on the another client

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have one simple page with input and add button. Below that I have list of all items.

```
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <form @submit.prevent="insertRoom" class="form-container" autocomplete="off" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <h3>Add room</h3>
      <label class="form-input-container" for="roomName">
        <input v-model="roomName" type="text" name="roomName" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Room name">
      </label>
      <input class="form-button" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    <list
      :list-title="'Room list'"
      :list-array="rooms"
      :remove-item="deleteRoom"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

How to refresh list of all items on the another client? For example if I open same page on two different PC, and if I add a new item (room). On the second PC this list of rooms doesn't change till I refresh page.

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
import List from '~/components/List.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    List
  },

  data () {
    return {
      roomName: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      rooms: state => state.rooms
    })
  },

  methods: {
    insertRoom () {
      this.addRoom({
        roomName: this.roomName
      })
    },

    deleteRoom (room) {
      this.removeRoom({
        roomName: room
      })
    },

    ...mapActions({
      addRoom: 'addRoom',
      removeRoom: 'removeRoom'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your data would need to be persisted outside the application, either on server or localStorage; and you'll need an observer to watch for changes in that data source.

Comment: If I open same page on two different pc, localStorage does not make sense?

Comment: You're correct, once multiple clients are involved, localStorage isn't a great solution - but your question asked about opening the page in two tabs, which is why I included localStorage as an option.

Comment: I'will change my question. I meant on something like live chat. If I change something, it should be refreshed on the another client.

Comment: This can't be achieved with Vuejs only. You need **a server** and **a bidirectional connection** (e.g. Websockets) to be able to push messages to the reciever.